# Razor Layout Page pre-set values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to convert an old masterpage (ASP.NET Webform) into Razor layout for new project. and I just wonder how can I set some values in the Razor layout by calling few other custom function. I know I can just write them in my layout page but it seems a bit messy. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

The best is to have the controller action pass whatever values a view might need in the view model. Another possibility is to use a custom HTML helper which would format the values. Or include a partial: `Html.Partial`, or render an action: [`Html.Action`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). Yet another possibility is to include a `@section`. So as you can see there are many ways, which one is best would depend on your exact scenario. I can though say which is the worst: write C# code in your views. The view shouldn't set anything. It should be as dumb as possible and simply render whatever information it is thrown to it by a controller.